# Does the device attributes section of Facebook's data policy entitle it to private files on my device?

Tags: privacy, facebook, iphone, information-gathering

I was reading through Facebook's data policy which also encompasses instagram, messenger, etc. It looked like the usual all encompassing breach of privacy I have come to expect from the company but one section in particular jumped out at me, it was under the device information section.

"Device attributes: information such as the operating system, hardware and software versions, battery level, signal strength, available storage space, browser type, app and file names and types, and plugins."

Now this last bit is kind of concerning, it seems to imply that facebook has free access to see what is in my phone whether that be personal banking pdf files or anything of the sort. They dont explain much what this means for obvious reasons but particularly the storage space, app and file names and types, and plugins seems ridiculously invasive. Are they really just specifying this for properly naming uploaded files like pictures etc, or does facebook just have copies of my files that I didnt give them somewhere in their system? If it helps I use an iPhone 6 running iOS 12.

Answer (score 2):

No, apps on iOS don't have free access to the file system. They need to ask for the user's permission to access personal files. To check what apps you have granted this permission to, go to **Settings** → **Privacy** → **Files**.